# Send selected row data in table to next page (Vaadin)

Tags: java, vaadin

How can I send selected row data in table to next page and write each column in TextField there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the select row with the getValue() method of the table.
This returns you the itemId of the selected row.

The rest should then not be a problem